# How to read pickle files created by another python version?

Tags: python, pandas, pickle

I often use pickle files to store my dataset. Currently I encounter a trouble. In my local desktop, the python version is python 3.8. However, In the remote server, the python version is python 3.7. I need to work in the remote server. So
I want to know how to read the pickle files created by the python 3.8?

```
import pandas as pd
df=pd.read_pickle('FUND_AREACLASS.pkl')
```

The report error is here:

```
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3_new\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\pickle.py", line 181, in read_pickle
return pickle.load(f)
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
```

Can anybody help me figure it out? Thanks in advance.

Comment: A dont think the problem is with python. but the problem seems to be with pandas. install the same version of pandas as on your server and it should work fine

Comment: Possible duplication of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329657/python-3-7-error-unsupported-pickle-protocol-5