# Unable to read pickle file with pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using Google Co lab
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5
python version 3.7.10
Link: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=1eF1BlfewbRhtgdJySjzU6esefYnr2xAC

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as 
plt
from glob import glob
from dateutil.relativedelta.    
import relativedelta, TH
import pickle
path = 
pd.DataFrame
(glob('/content/drive/MyDrive
/sample_nfo_201920_data/
complete_nfo_data_2019-01- 
01.pkl'),columns = 
['location'])

path['location']
.iloc[0].split('_')[-1]
.split('.')[0]

path['data_date']= 
path['location'].apply(lambda.  
x: x.split('_')[-1].split('.') 
[0])

path['data_date']= 
path['data_date'].
apply(lambda.   x: 
datetime.datetime.
strptime(x,'%Y-%m-%d'))

path=path.sort_values
(['data_date'])

pd.read_pickle
("/content/drive/MyDrive
/sample_nfo_2019- 
20_data/complete_nfo_data_
2019-01-01.pkl")
```

Error:
ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol:5

Answer (score 1):

Use [pckle5](https://pypi.org/project/pickle5/) or you can do this all in Python 3.8+.

Comment: I am using Google Co lab it having version 3.7. So I want to access from python 3.7

Comment: Then use pickle5.

Comment: Tried with pickle5 but same error is coming.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65318801/10343540


Did you do this?