# Pkl.File import can't be read "ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5"

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, import

here the exemplary code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pickle5 as pickle

#Read
output = pd.read_pickle("Energy_data.pkl")
plt.figure()
#print(output)
output.plot()
```

I am using Python 3.7 and that is probably the reason for the error message, because this .pkl files were created in Python 3.8 . If my colleague runs it (he created the .pkl-Files), it'll work.

I tried to use this solution (maybe I did not do it correctly) shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329657/python-3-7-error-unsupported-pickle-protocol-5), but it did not work anyway. Can  someone show me how to import the pkl files using the example above in Python 3.7?

Thank you very much in advance!