# Pandas error on Google Colab: Unsupported pickle protocol: 5

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, google-colaboratory, pickle, hdf5

It gives the following error `ValueError: unsupported pickle protocol: 5` it arises from this line `a=pd.read_hdf('onedata.h5','30-70cancerChdEtc (1)')`. My Google Colab's Python version is `3.7.12` and I wrote my code with Python version `3.8.5`. I am guessing the error is due to the different python versions. Any help appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63329657/python-3-7-error-unsupported-pickle-protocol-5

Comment: I think the error was due hdf5 file which was written in python 3.6 and it doesn't supported pickle 5. It works fine in 3.8. Thank you.